# Getting DaVinci 16.2 Resolve to Work with Intel Gen 4 Graphics

Tags: davinci-resolve

I am currently trying to give DaVinci a try for my video editing needs. However, I am running into issues, which seem to be graphics card related.

It crashes like this (from the logs):

```
[0x7fb0b796c000] | Main                 | INFO  | 2020-04-06 13:25:43,873 | Running DaVinci Resolve v16.2.0.055 (Linux/Clang)
[0x7fb0b796c000] | Main                 | INFO  | 2020-04-06 13:25:43,874 | Updating display GPU information...
OpenCL error -1001: 'Unspecified Error', GPUPropertiesUtilUnix.cpp:338.
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'ReactorGPU::GPUException'


==========[CRASH DUMP]==========
Please send this to support:

#TIME Mon Apr  6 13:25:43 2020 - Uptime 00:00:00 (hh:mm:ss)
#PROGRAM_NAME DaVinci Resolve v16.2.0.055 (Linux/Clang)

/opt/resolve/bin/resolve() [0x54a0029]
/opt/resolve/bin/resolve() [0x549f81a]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0(+0x12890) [0x7fb0c1d4e890]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(gsignal+0xc7) [0x7fb0bfad2e97]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(abort+0x141) [0x7fb0bfad4801]
/opt/resolve/bin/resolve(_ZN9__gnu_cxx27__verbose_terminate_handlerEv+0x15d) [0x720748d]
/opt/resolve/bin/../libs/libc++abi.so.1(+0x22086) [0x7fb0f3e58086]
/opt/resolve/bin/../libs/libc++abi.so.1(+0x21a27) [0x7fb0f3e57a27]
/opt/resolve/bin/resolve() [0x1fabdbc]
/opt/resolve/bin/resolve() [0x1fab589]
/opt/resolve/bin/resolve() [0x1fa539c]
/opt/resolve/bin/resolve() [0x1f727cc]
/opt/resolve/bin/resolve() [0x1f6f8de]
/opt/resolve/bin/resolve() [0x1f6e33e]
/opt/resolve/bin/resolve() [0x1f6dbe8]
/opt/resolve/bin/resolve() [0x1f8299a]
/opt/resolve/bin/resolve() [0x1f698ff]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(__libc_start_main+0xe7) [0x7fb0bfab5b97]
/opt/resolve/bin/resolve() [0x1f68b7d]
Signal Number = 6
```

The CPU and Graphics card on this machine are as follows:

```
  *-display                 
       description: VGA compatible controller
       product: Xeon E3-1200 v3/4th Gen Core Processor Integrated Graphics Controller
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 2
       bus info: pci@0000:00:02.0
       version: 06
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: msi pm vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
       configuration: driver=i915 latency=0
       resources: irq:32 memory:f7800000-f7bfffff memory:e0000000-efffffff ioport:f000(size=64) memory:c0000-dffff

     *-cpu
          description: CPU
          product: Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-4790K CPU @ 4.00GHz
          bus info: cpu@0
          version: Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-4790K CPU @ 4.00GHz
          slot: CPUSocket
          capabilities: x86-64 fpu fpu_exception wp vme de pse tsc msr pae mce cx8 apic sep mtrr pge mca cmov pat pse36 clflush dts acpi mmx fxsr sse sse2 ss ht tm pbe syscall nx pdpe1gb rdtscp constant_tsc arch_perfmon pebs bts rep_good nopl xtopology nonstop_tsc cpuid aperfmperf pni pclmulqdq dtes64 monitor ds_cpl vmx est tm2 ssse3 sdbg fma cx16 xtpr pdcm pcid sse4_1 sse4_2 x2apic movbe popcnt tsc_deadline_timer aes xsave avx f16c rdrand lahf_lm abm cpuid_fault invpcid_single pti ssbd ibrs ibpb stibp tpr_shadow vnmi flexpriority ept vpid fsgsbase tsc_adjust bmi1 avx2 smep bmi2 erms invpcid xsaveopt dtherm ida arat pln pts md_clear flush_l1d cpufreq
             slot: CPU Internal L1
             slot: CPU Internal L2
             slot: CPU Internal L3
```

More specifically, the graphics card is a Gen 4 Intel 4600.

Does anyone know if it is possible to get DaVinci working on this system? If so, how should I troubleshoot this issue?

Answer (score 2):

Black Magic Design have recently released Resolve version 16.2.1 with "Improved stability on Windows systems with Intel graphics" - which may help, but generally speaking support and performance on Integrated CPU's has always been limited. I can run DR on my Laptop with an Intel HD 520, but only for very basic & slow editing.

You also did not say when it crashes. i.e. At startup / playback / edit, and what media was being processed (if any).

**Minimum system requirements for Windows:** 
Windows 10 Update 
16 GB of system memory. 32 GB when using Fusion 
Blackmagic Design Desktop Video version 10.4.1 or later 
Integrated GPU or discrete GPU with at least 2GB of VRAM 
GPU which supports OpenCL 1.2 or CUDA 10 
NVIDIA/AMD/Intel GPU Driver version

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I am actually on an Ubuntu 18.04 machine. Yes, it crashes on startup.